# php custom c extension with external shared lib

Tags: php, c, linux

I would like to develop an extension which depends on an external shared library. My current problem is that I am not being able to link this shared library to my extension.

My development environment is Fedora Linux x64 + PHP 5.4. This external shared library is a proprietary one, I just have its headers (.h) and .so files (for 32 and 64 bits).

The project's current config.m4 file is as follows:

```
PHP_ARG_WITH(projectname,
    [Whether to enable ProjectName support],
    [  --with-projectname              enable ProjectName support])

if test "$PHP_PROJECTNAME" != "no"; then
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(externallib, lib64, PROJECTNAME_SHARED_LIBADD)

    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_PROJECTNAME, 1, [Whether you have ProjectName])
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(projectname, projectname.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

The problem here is every time I run `./configure --with-projectname` the generated makefile does not have any reference to the library, plus the compiled .so file fails (obviously).

It would also be useful if I had a way to determine the right lib directory according to the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You've included the library, but looks you're missing the actual link option. I haven't done this in the longest time, but I think something like the following should work.

```
EXTERNAL_LIB="blahLibName"
LIB_LINK_CMD="-L/usr/local/lib -l$EXTERNAL_LIB"

PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(externallib, lib64, PROJECTNAME_SHARED_LIBADD)
PHP_EVAL_LIBLINE($LIB_LINK_CMD, PROJECTNAME_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

The syntax here might not be right at all, but you definitely need the PHP_EVAL_LIBLINE.